# Create an admin user programmatically in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, admin

Recently I had a client come to me to build a new website. They had also forgotten all their login details, but they did have FTP access.

How do you create an admin user programmatically in WordPress?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This will create an admin user if placed in a themes functions.php file. Please change the first three variables as needed.

```
/* 
* Create an admin user silently
*/

add_action('init', 'xyz1234_my_custom_add_user');

function xyz1234_my_custom_add_user() {
    $username = 'username123';
    $password = 'pasword123';
    $email = 'drew@example.com';

    if (username_exists($username) == null && email_exists($email) == false) {

        // Create the new user
        $user_id = wp_create_user($username, $password, $email);

        // Get current user object
        $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role('subscriber');

        // Add role
        $user->add_role('administrator');
    }
}
```

Comment: https://wpcode.blog/how-to-create-user-in-wordpress-programmatically/

check here with explanation

Answer (score 28):

Accepted answer has issues and will throw a fatal error when its run twice, because the `$user_id` will be empty the second time. A work around for the issue:

```
function rndprfx_add_user() {
    $username = 'username123';
    $password = 'azerty321';
    $email = 'example@example.com';

    if (username_exists($username) == null && email_exists($email) == false) {
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
        $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );
        $user->add_role( 'administrator' );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'rndprfx_add_user');
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the queries to create a **new admin user** :

```
INSERT INTO wp_users (user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_status) VALUES ('newadmin', MD5('pass123'), 'firstname lastname', 'email@example.com', '0');

INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (NULL, (Select max(id) FROM wp_users), 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');

INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (NULL, (Select max(id) FROM wp_users), 'wp_user_level', '10');
```

Comment: Not recommended to go this route, WordPress has built in functions to handle user creation.

Comment: Yes wordpress have but sometimes if we dont have login credentials and we are working for a client. So in that case we needs to make a admin user from backend to login.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you need to add this code sample in your functions.php:

```
function wpb_admin_account(){
  $user = 'Username';
  $pass = 'Password';
  $email = 'email@domain.com';
  if ( !username_exists( $user )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email );
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user->set_role( 'administrator' );
  } 
}
add_action('init','wpb_admin_account');
```

Do not forget to change Username, Password and Email by your own data.
here is more detailed tutorials that might help you.
[How to create a new WordPress admin user programmatically](https://wphub.me/wordpress/create-new-wordpress-admin-user-programmatically/)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the examples provided above I would like to give some extra tips.

First of all, you can not just use this code inside `init` hook – in this case WordPress will try to create a user on every page load.

Second, why using `wp_create_user()` when you can use `wp_insert_user()` function?

Correct example:

```
add_action( 'init', function() ) {
    // do nothing if we didn't provide ?create_user_123=anything in the URL
    if( empty( $_GET[ 'create_user_123' ] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_insert_user( 
        array(
            'user_login' => 'user login goes here', 
            'user_pass' => 'password will go here',
            'role' => 'administrator',
        )
    );

});
```

I took the example from here https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/create-user-programmatically.html#create-admin-user