# Create new user automatically via functions.php in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add new user with admin role via code, and I found this code:

```
add_action('init', 'add_user');
function add_user() {
    $username = 'username123';
    $password = 'pasword123';
    $email = 'drew@example.com';

    // Create the new user
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );

    // Get current user object
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

    // Remove role
    $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

    // Add role
    $user->add_role( 'administrator' );
}
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308808/create-an-admin-user-programmatically-in-wordpress)

But when I added it in `functions.php`, I got this error :

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function remove_role() 
 on a non-object in ..../functions.php on line ...
```

I also tried this code:

```
 function fb_wp_insert_user() {
$user_data = array(
'ID' => '',
'user_pass' => wp_generate_password(),
'user_login' => 'dummy',
'user_nicename' => 'Dummy',
'user_url' => '',
'user_email' => 'dummy@example.com',
'display_name' => 'Dummy',
'nickname' => 'dummy',
'first_name' => 'Dummy',
'user_registered' => '2010-05-15 05:55:55',
'role' => get_option('default_role') // Use default role or another role, e.g. 'editor'
);
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'fb_wp_insert_user' );
```

I changed default role to `adminstrator` but when I browsed the users, I found this user without any role.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is your error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function remove_role() on a non-object
>   in ..../functions.php on line ...

It's is because of `$user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );` code and it means that, when you are using following code to retrieve the new user

```
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
```

It's not returning a [WP_User](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) object. So, if you call a method on a non object, this error shows up and it could be because you didn't get an `ID` when you used

```
$user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
```

It's possible that, you didn't successfully created a user and in this case the return value could be an `object` according to `Codex`

> When successful - this function returns the user ID of the created
>   user. In case of failure (username or email already exists) the
>   function returns an error object, with these possible values and
>   messages;
>
> empty_user_login, Cannot create a user with an empty login name.
>
> existing_user_login, This username is already registered.
>
> existing_user_email, This email address is already registered.

SO, when you are creating a user, at first check if the user exist or not like

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_user');
function add_my_user() {
    $username = 'username123';
    $email = 'drew@example.com';
    $password = 'pasword123';

    $user_id = username_exists( $username );
    if ( !$user_id && email_exists($email) == false ) {
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
        if( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
            $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
            $user->set_role( 'administrator' );
        }
    }
}
```

Also, there is no need for reomving and adding the role, [set_role($role)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#set_role.28.24role.29) will remove the previous roles of the user and assign the user the new one.
Read more about [wp create user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) and [get user by](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) on `Codex`. Also, check the [wp_generate_password()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_password) to use a secured password instead of plain text.

**Update :**

[add_user](http://wpseek.com/add_user/) is a WordPress function, so change the name to something else like, `add_my_user`.

Comment: @RCV please put full code , i use your code and see this : Cannot redeclare add_user() (previously declared in ..\functions.php:909) in ..\wp-admin\includes\user.php on line 18 . 909 is : $username = 'username123'; . maybe i am not understand you correctly . please put your full code.

Comment: ooooops same error !!  Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_user() (previously declared in ..\functions.php:909) in ..\wp-admin\includes\user.php on line 18 , 909 is $username = 'username123';

Comment: Check the update, Changed `add_user` to `add_my_user` @techno.

Comment: If you´re not using this in a plugin, don't forget to use the: require_once "wp-load.php";

Answer (score 7):

Check to make sure that [`wp_create_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) actually *created* the user:

```
add_action('init', 'add_user');
function add_user() {
    $username = 'username123';
    $password = 'pasword123';
    $email = 'drew@example.com';

    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $email );
    if( ! $user ) {

        // Create the new user
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
        if( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
            // examine the error message
            echo( "Error: " . $user_id->get_error_message() );
            exit;
        }

        // Get current user object
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    }

    // Remove role
    $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

    // Add role
    $user->add_role( 'administrator' );
}
```

**Edited**: Per the comments below, it appears that the user has already been created.  I've updated the code to check for that. (In essence, now, if the user doesn't already exist, it'll be created.)

#### References

- [`get_user_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)
- [`wp_create_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in ..\functions.php on line 917 . line 917 is : echo( "Error: " . $user_id->get_error_message();

Comment: Whoops, fixed my typo.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare add_user() (previously declared in ..\functions.php:909) in ..\wp-admin\includes\user.php on line 18 909 is : $username = 'username123';

Comment: @AmalMurali Huh? If `wp_create_user()` returns a `WP_Error` object, I check to see what the error is. Otherwise, `$user` should be a `WP_User` object, unless, for some reason, `wp_create_user()` returned *neither* an integer ID nor a `WP_Error` object.

Comment: @AmalMurali  i  got the error message :  "Error: " . $user_id->get_error_message() , the user is already registered

Answer (score 4):

```
$userData = array(
            'user_login' => 'username',
            'first_name' => 'First',
            'last_name' => 'Last',
            'user_pass' => 'password',
            'user_email' => 'you@mail.com',
            'user_url' => '',
            'role' => 'administrator'
        );
wp_insert_user( $userData );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function kechweb_create_admin_account(){
  $user = 'Username'; <br />
  $pass = 'Password';<br />
  $email = 'email@domain.com';<br />
  //if a username with the email ID does not exist, create a new user account<br />
  if ( !username_exists( $user ) && !email_exists( $email ) ) {<br />
  $user_id = wp_create_user( $user, $pass, $email ); <br />
  $user = new WP_User( $user_id ); <br />
  //Set the new user as a Admin <br />
  $user->set_role( 'administrator' ); <br />
  } } <br />
  add_action('init','kechweb_create_admin_account');
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the original question and which information it brings which has not already been brought in the other answers.