# How to change WordPress website just with files

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How to change content of website build in WordPress when I only have access to files on hosting? I can't use wp-admin so that's what I'm left with.

Comment: Why can't you use `wp-admin`? - it is just a folder, right?

Answer (score 1):

You Can't Do That™.

The only thing you can change without access to wp-admin is the contents of image files. Most of WordPress's content lives in the associated MariaDB or MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you access wp-admin? if you lost access to it(like no username/pass etc), and since you do have access to the FTP server, then you can backdoor your way in. Check out this post here on SO. Should steer you in the right direction.

[Create new user automatically via functions.php in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845192/create-new-user-automatically-via-functions-php-in-wordpress)

If you still can't get in for whatever reason, and since you want to primarily edit the content as you previously stated, then there is still a way.

Assuming you have access to the HOSTING server, you can still edit the content via the backend database itself. Again, assuming you have access, go ahead and log into the server, and find your way towards **PHPMYADMIN**.

Once you are in there, look for a database table called `wp_posts`:

[image]

All your content will be in there.

PLEASE NOTE: if you gain access to the backend MYSQL server, and cant tell which database is which, FTP in to the site, and find the `wp_config.php` file, and towards the top, you should see something like

DEFINE database name (or something like that, been a minute)
but you should see the database name there, to which you can match on the PHP MYADMIN side of things.

hope this steers you in the right direction.

Good luck.